# Validation of input text fields with javascript regex match

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate 2 text fields inside a form with a little help of regular expressions, but I'm getting an error on regex match while looping through field values - on form submit I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: elem.match is not a function".

I want to use date format dd.mm.yyyy and I need to use text fields, can't use date fields.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="checkForm(); return false;" action="#">

<input type="text" id="jform0" name="jform0" value="12.12.2020" class="calendar_date">
<input type="text" id="jform1" name="jform1" value="12.12.2020" class="calendar_date">

<input type="submit" value="Posodobi">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkForm() {
  // regular expression to match required date format
  re = /^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/;

  document.querySelectorAll(".calendar_date").forEach((elem) => {
    if (elem.value != "" && !elem.match(re)) {
      alert("Invalid date format: " + elem.value);
      elem.focus();
      return false;
    }
  });

  alert("All input fields have been validated!");
  return true;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/esedic/4gtn1hw3/13/

Any idea, why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Use `elem.value.match(...)` not `elem.match(...)`

Comment: Of course, thank you!